# Registro duplicado - Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

No Firebird como deletar os registros duplicados, mantendo apenas um deles? Aguém poderia me ajudar. tenho esse select, porém ele deleta todos os registros, uso firebird 2.1

```
        delete from vendaproduto where vendaproduto.pro_codigo in
        (select vendaproduto.pro_codigo from vendaproduto where
        VENDAPRODUTO.ven_codigo = 2432
        having COUNT(*) != 1)
```

Comment: Se possível, coloque o código SQL envolvido (criação das tabela e consulta) no [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/), assim fica mais fácil ainda ajudarmos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe mais de uma forma para fazer isto. Com base no SQL mostrado, é possível fazer desta maneira:

```
DELETE FROM vendaproduto 
        WHERE
          pro_codigo IN (
            SELECT a.pro_codigo FROM vendaproduto a 
              WHERE a.pro_codigo in ( 
                   SELECT b.pro_codigo FROM vendaproduto b 
                   WHERE a.pro_codigo = b.pro_codigo 
                   AND a.ven_codigo = b.ven_codigo 
                   AND b.ven_codigo = 2432 
                   GROUP BY b.pro_codigo 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) != 1 )
          )
```

Ou [desta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15548695/2387977), sem `HAVING`:

```
DELETE FROM vendaproduto vp
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT MIN(pro_codigo) pro_codigo, ven_codigo
            FROM vendaproduto
            GROUP BY pro_codigo
        ) b ON vp.pro_codigo = b.pro_codigo AND
                vp.ven_codigo = b.ven_codigo
                AND b.ven_codigo = 2432 --se remover esta linha, ele busca e elimina todos os registros com pro_codigo e pro_codigo duplicados no banco de dados, mantendo o último registro
            WHERE b.pro_codigo IS NULL
```

Ou ainda [esta](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/deleting-duplicate-rows-keeping-intact-631346.html), que é a minha preferida, por ser a mais simples de entender:

```
DELETE
  FROM
    vendaproduto 
WHERE
  pro_codigo IN (
  SELECT
    a.pro_codigo
  FROM
    vendaproduto a
  WHERE
    a.pro_codigo < (
      SELECT MAX(b.pro_codigo)
      FROM
        vendaproduto  b
      WHERE
        a.pro_codigo = b.pro_codigo
        AND a.ven_codigo = b.ven_codigo 
        AND b.ven_codigo = 2432 
    )
  )
```

Em todas elas, removendo a linha correspondente ao filtro do código `2432`, é possível remover todos os duplicados, mantendo o registro mais recente.